# array_keys function with search value is an array returns empty as result in php (No Foreach)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
$full_json ='{
"1stelement": {
"2ndelement": {
  "elements": [
    {
      "test1": 383,
      "test2": 100
    },
    {
      "test1": 48,
      "test2": 5
    },
    {
      "test1": 383,
      "test2": 100
    },
    {
      "test1": 48,
      "test2": 6
    },
    {
      "test1": 383,
      "test2": 100
    },
    {
      "test1": 48,
      "test2": 7
    },
    {
      "test1": 383,
      "test2": 100
    },
    {
      "test1": 48,
      "test2": 8
    },
    {
      "test1": 383,
      "test2": 100
    },
    {
      "test1": 48,
      "test2": 9
    },
    {
      "test1": 383,
      "test2": 100
    },
    {
      "test1": 48,
      "test2": 10
    }
  ]
}
}
}';

$full = json_decode($full_json,true);
$test2range = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20);
$values=array_keys(array_column($full['1stelement']['2ndelement']['elements'], 'test2'),$test2range ,true);
// $values=array_keys(array_column($full['1stelement']['2ndelement']['elements'], 'test2'),5 ,true); // returns result
var_dump($values);
exit;
```

I want to get [array_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) return values to process further.

Without array_keys function, we can get the values using foreach loop which is not advisable.

As per **array_keys** definition, search value parameter can be of [mixed type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.mixed), So we can give array of values.

When I tried that, result always give as an empty array which is not an expected result.

Can anyone explain how to accomplish this?

Comment: `array_keys() ` supports only single values like this `print_r(array_keys($a,"10",true));`

Comment: OP seem to know it support single value (as his example that works for single value), his question is why not multi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [array_keys source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c#L3942) there is type comparison before (in function `fast_is_identical_function`) - this why array not supported - as the core code is not able to break the array.

What the `mix_value` mean is that you can compare array with array or int with int... - but not multi option of search.

However, you can do like this:

```
$values = array_keys(array_filter($full['1stelement']['2ndelement']['elements'], function ($e) use ($test2range) {return in_array($e["test2"], $test2range);}));
```

Or you can implement it yourself:

```
function array_keys_multi_search($arr, $searchValues, $strict) {
    $res = array();
    foreach($searchValues as $v)
        $res = array_merge($res, array_keys($arr, $v, $strict));
    return $res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `array_intersect()` to check matched keys.

```
$full = json_decode($full_json,true);

$test2range = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20);

$values= array_column($full['1stelement']['2ndelement']['elements'], 'test2');

$result=array_intersect($test2range,$values);

var_dump($result);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

decode your json array

```
$full = (array) json_decode($this->input->post($full_json);
```

then use foreach to get values

```
 foreach($full['1stelement']['2ndelement']['elements'] as $key => $values){

}
```

Comment: The OP look for the keys not values

Comment: use $key variable to get keys